# Fetching specific fields of a document in bulk

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following Schema

```
Schema = {
   field1: String, //secret
   field2: String, //public
   field3: String, //secret
   field4: String, //secret
   field5: String, //public
   field6: String, //secret
   ...
   field45: String, //public
}
```

I want to fetch only the 'public' fields from my document. 
I can obviously ask for specific fields in my query, but there are many fields and I am trying to find out if there's a way to "flag" secret fields and only fetch the ones that are not secret.

Something like that:

```
Schema = {
   field1: {type:String, flag:true}, //secret
   field2: {type:String, flag:false}, //public
   field3: {type:String, flag:true}, //secret
   field4: {type:String, flag:true}, //secret
   field5: {type:String, flag:false}, //public
   field6: {type:String, flag:true}, //secret
   ...
   field45: {type:String, flag:false} //public
}
```

I know I can separate the fields into two different schemas: one of public fields, and one for secret fields, but at this point in the project this is unfortunately not practical.

Question 2: 
If there is a way to fetch selectively when querying a database, is there a way to do a similar action when the fetched document is a referred sub-document in a populated document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongoose, you can use `select` field. From [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) :

> select: {Boolean} - Specifies default path selection behavior. In
>   other words, you can specify if this path should be included or
>   excluded from query results by default.

Hence :

```
new Schema({
  field1: { type: String, select: true }, // select: true is optional
  field2: { type: String, select: false },
  ...
})
```

You can still access it with `.find({}, { field2: 1 })` or `.find({}).select('+field2')`

Comment: but I have dozens of fields I want to select. I am looking for a way to select them without explicitly naming each field. That's the point.

Comment: oh sorry! Misread your answer! Thank you! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Another question. Is this also applicable when the document is a populated subdocument?

Comment: Lastly, is there a way to tell mongoose to give me all the fields regardless of the select attr.?

Comment: To select all fields regardless of the select attr, I would suggest to create an object `allWantedFields = { field: 1, field2: 2 ... }` and `.find({}, allWantedFields)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't use the json schema as you should.

For this, try to not use dynamic fields, but as objects:

```
schema : [
   {
       "name" : "field1",
       "type" : "String",
       "flag" : true
   }
]
```

Thus, you're able to select it by flags:

```
db.your_collection.find({"schema.flag": true})
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. But thank you.